# How do I get the executable name during the Custom Installer Action of a setup?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I'm trying to get the executable name for my project during the custom action portion of my installation.  For this reason it seems I can't use anything in `System.Reflection` which limits my options considerably.  I am able to get the target direction via the `/targetdir="[TARGETDIR]\"` attribute in CustomActionData and then using:

```
Context.Parameters["targetdir"]
```

But I can't seem to get the actual exe name to finish of the path.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The executable that runs a Windows Installer setup is msiexec.exe, the windows process. It might help to say what problem you are trying to solve that makes you think that the solution is knowing this. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My installer has a Radio Button element where the buttons represent the install environment (Dev, QA, Shadow, Prod, ect).  And based on what is picked at the installer, I need to update settings in app.config.  For instance, if dev is picked, the server to be used for a certain operation is DEVSERVER1, but if QA is picked it needs to be QASERVER5 and so on.  I was using `ConfigurationManager` but `OpenExeConfiguration()` needs the path to the exe.

Comment: So you are running an executable as a custom action, and even though run explicitly run the exe from a custom action you don't know its name? It's hardcoded in the setup so it's not clear to me why you don't know the name. Have you tried Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase  ?

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` uses Reflection, and you said Windows Installers Setup is msiexec.exe, so reflection is useless.